# Youtrack Installation, Java not found

Tags: java, linux, unix, path, youtrack

I am getting the following error message:

> Java executable of version 1.7 is not found:
>   - Java executable is not found under the specified directories: 'internal/java/mac-x64', 'internal/java/windows-x86'
>   - Neither the JAVA_HOME nor the JRE_HOME environment variable is defined
>   - Java executable is not found in the directories listed in the PATH environment variable
>
> Please make sure one of the environment variables is defined and is
>   pointing to valid Java (JRE) installation, then run again Environment
>   variable FJ_DEBUG can be set to enable debug output
>
> Java not found. Please ensure JDK or JRE is installed and JAVA_HOME
>   environment variable points to it. youtrack.sh: 12: exit: Illegal
>   number: -1

But I do have a JDK installed on my linux server:

```
root@ikw:/home/ad# update-alternatives --display java
java - auto mode
  link currently points to /usr/bin/gij-4.7
/opt/jdk/jdk1.7.0_75/bin/java - priority 100
/usr/bin/gij-4.7 - priority 1047
Current 'best' version is '/usr/bin/gij-4.7'
```

I also have the path variables cofig in the file: `.profile`

```
JAVA_HOME='/usr/bin/gij-4.7/opt/jdk/jdk1.7.0_75/bin/java'
export JAVA_HOME
PATH="$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH"
export PATH
```

Any idea how to fix the java issue to be able to install youtrack?

Comment: JAVA_HOME should point to JRE folder, not to java executable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of:

```
JAVA_HOME='/usr/bin/gij-4.7/opt/jdk/jdk1.7.0_75/bin/java'
```

Try this:

```
JAVA_HOME='/usr/bin/gij-4.7/opt/jdk/jdk1.7.0_75'
```

Answer (score 1):

This line is completely wrong, this path does not exist on your system with security.

`JAVA_HOME='/usr/bin/gij-4.7/opt/jdk/jdk1.7.0_75/bin/java'`

Chane your `JAVA_HOME`:

```
JAVA_HOME='/opt/jdk/jdk1.7.0_75'
```

Comment: @user3576148 interesting first: "that was the solution" and an accepted answer and now nothing?